# Why i have Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null error?

Tags: javascript, css, function

HTML:

```
 <body>
<script src="dynamic.js"></script>
<nav>
  <label id="logo">My Life</label>
  <ul id="test">
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="change">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Feedback</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="active">Log in</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

JavaScript:

```
const change = document.getElementById("change");
change.addEventListener("mouseover", () => changeFont());
change.addEventListener("mouseout", () => normalFont());

function changeFont() {
  change.style.fontSize = "25px";
}

function normalFont() {
  change.style.fontSize = "15px";
}
```

I have simple navigation bar and when i decide to make it more interesting with hover effect I decide to be with JS NOT CSS and when i run the code in chrome i have a "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" error and I can't figure out why?

I need some help ...

Comment: put the script at the bottom of the page before closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: It's likely that your script is running before the DOM is rendered. So when you call `document.getElementById("change")` the element doesn't exist yet. As @Muhammad says above, moving your script to the bottom of the document should fix it.

Comment: Adding `defer` to the script tag should do the trick as well.

Answer (score 1):

Because `<script>` in the beggining of the file. So when it executes element `change` is not loaded and so variable is `null`. Put your script in the end of the document or set the attribute `defer`. Scripts with this attribute wait when the DOM will be loaded and after that execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap your code in a [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to make sure it only fires after the DOM is ready.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const change = document.getElementById("change");
  change.addEventListener("mouseover", () => changeFont());
  change.addEventListener("mouseout", () => normalFont());

  function changeFont() {
    change.style.fontSize = "25px";
  }

  function normalFont() {
    change.style.fontSize = "15px";
  }
});
```

Snippet before the change (error thrown)

```html
<script>
  const change = document.getElementById("change");
  change.addEventListener("mouseover", () => changeFont());
  change.addEventListener("mouseout", () => normalFont());

  function changeFont() {
    change.style.fontSize = "25px";
  }

  function normalFont() {
    change.style.fontSize = "15px";
  }
</script>
<nav>
  <label id="logo">My Life</label>
  <ul id="test">
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="change">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Feedback</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="active">Log in</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

snippet after change (no error)

```html
<script>
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const change = document.getElementById("change");
    change.addEventListener("mouseover", () => changeFont());
    change.addEventListener("mouseout", () => normalFont());

    function changeFont() {
      change.style.fontSize = "25px";
    }

    function normalFont() {
      change.style.fontSize = "15px";
    }
  });
</script>
<nav>
  <label id="logo">My Life</label>
  <ul id="test">
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="change">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Feedback</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="active">Log in</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

But anyway, besides that, you actually don't need to use javascript if you're only changing the element font-size on hover. You can do that with [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) like so

Pure CSS snippet

```css
#change:hover,
#change:active,
#change:focus {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <label id="logo">My Life</label>
  <ul id="test">
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="change">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Feedback</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="active">Log in</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```